# Asymptote dictionaries.

Tags: asymptote

I have been looking through the [manual](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/asymptote.pdf) of Asymptote and it seems it does not have Hash-Tables or dictionaries.

Are they present in the language? It does seem like a glaring omission for what otherwise seems like almost a full-blown computer language. Possibly there are libraries for this?

Comment: I do not believe they are pre-defined in Asymptote.  I think you could define them using structures and sorting routines.  I don't think they exist in the C programming language either, but I still consider it a "full-blown computer language".

Comment: @ James Good point! :-D